# Is it normal for an Evenk/Siberian hitch knot to become loose?

Tags: knots

Is it normal for the [Evenk/Siberian](http://www.howlbushcraft.com/bushcraft-blog/2017/6/18/tarp-knots-the-evenk-hitch) hitch knot to open out in use, particularly when tied to a large diameter object (think tree) where the rope enters the knot close to right angles from the load?

I'm 99% sure I'm [tying it correctly](http://www.animatedknots.com/siberian/),   but no matter how slowly and carefully I work the knot up, after pulling it up into position and under load it seems to open out into 2 separate parts. Due to the mechanics of the knot it seems to hold from my quick testing, but I don't know. It's meant to be okay for hammock usage but it's not giving me any sort of confidence in it. Not the "in a sack, over a rock" confidence you'd want anyhow.

Alternatively, does anyone have a good alternative slippery hitch that can be pulled up into a tree above head height and released again, and suitable for hammock use? I've looked at a few which may fit the bill, but I'd  be interested to know what people actually use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, yes. It's not the most secure of knots, it'll do in many situations but I wouldn't want to trust my life with it under any circumstances!

You might want to try the [Slipped Buntline](http://notableknotindex.webs.com/slippedbuntline.html) as a more secure alternative.

Comment: i've just noticed on a ray mears video that he puts an extra loop in for security on the hammock but not the tarp. that's likely what i was missing.